# Rep change bug in new user overlay

Tags: bug, status-completed

The user overlay shows more rep points gained in the current week than in the current month:

[image]

Given that we are in the middle of a month, I'd say that's a bug.

Comment: Was this on the meta or on the main site?

Comment: @NickCraver On the main site. Meta shows today 0 week 0 month 422 - 0, cause the week has just started, but 422 and the 426 from the screenshot also don't add up. askubuntu.com/reputation shows that the rep is off by some points, but also had this smaller month value.

Comment: I see what the issue is, there was a calculation bug in our global recalc that wasn't saving the week/month/quarter/year correctly a few weeks ago...ubuntu never got another run for affected users.  We'll correct this in a run tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Nick Craver this was a calculation bug that is now fixed.